# Firebase notifications iOS in react native

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, apple-push-notifications, react-native-ios

I'm actually on a chat application using react-native and I have a database on firebase. I have the notifications on android whenever an user post a new message but on iOS it doesn't work. In my code, I subscribe the user into a topic when he send a message.

```
export const sendMessage = message => {
      return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(chatMessageLoading())
        let currentUser = firebaseService.auth().currentUser
        let createdAt = new Date().getTime()
        let chatMessageCars = {
          text: message,
          createdAt: createdAt,
          user: {
            id: currentUser.uid,
            email: currentUser.email,
          }
        }

        FIREBASE_REF_CARS.push().set(chatMessageCars, (error) => {
          if (error) {
            dispatch(chatMessageError(error.message))
          } else {
            dispatch(chatMessageSuccess())
            FCM.requestPermissions();
            firebase.messaging().subscribeToTopic('Nextdoor')
          }
        })
      }
    }
```

I have the apple developer program and I have enabled push notifications and remote notifications.

Thanks !